# PNP PowerShell Connect-PnpOnline with -AccessToken is not setting connection in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, function, powershell, sharepoint-online

I have an Azure Function which is using PnpPowershell. I'd like to work with the users authorization. So I created a service which is getting an OAuth token from Microsoft for the user. I then give the token to the Azure Function to use it to connect via *Connect-PnpOnline*.

```
Connect-PnpOnline -AccessToken $token -Url $url
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate "Template.xml"
```

*Connect-PnpOnline* executes without any errors/warnings, but *Apply-PnpProvisioningTemplate* raises the following error: ***The current connection holds no SharePoint context. Please use one of the Connect-PnPOnline commands which uses the -Url argument to connect.***

I'd have expected the connection to be in place. I can use this token to query the MS Graph, so I'd have expected it to be valid. Does anyone have tried something similar and have an idea how to solve the issue?

Found this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps

https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2631

https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the error and my understanding is that you will have to make use of the token obtained through the Sharepoint App(Sharepoint Add in)  in the **Connect-PNPOnline** - This commandlet is specific to sharepoint.

Graph is more of a wrapper of multiple technologies - internally speak to sharepoint. So they might not have context of Sharepoint in specific.

So my suggestion would be make use of the token obtained from Sharepoint app (Sharepoint add in) - Get auth against the sharepoint URL. ( For instance : https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/OAuthAuthorize.aspx  unlike in Azure App you will be making use of login.microsoftonline.com)

For detailed steps of registering and using the Sharepoint App you could refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/authorization-code-oauth-flow-for-sharepoint-add-ins)

Comment: @greg - just wanted to check with you whether the above answer helped or have any further queries ?

Comment: thank you. You were right I had to use a token from the tenant. One thing to mention, the obtained token needs full access the Sharepoint to work at all since PNP wants to be executed by admins not by users.